# Openning a new Activity using expandable Listview's child

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, expandablelistview

I have a problem with ExapandableListView, I don't know how to open activity by clicking on a child's expandable list View. I've created an ExpandableListView and I want to open an Activity by clicking on a child in this list. I want to open that activity based on what type of subject is mentioned in the child list. Can you please help me. I'll be very thankful for any help.

```
    SessionManager user= new SessionManager(profil_etd.this);

    Query CheckUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("etd").orderByChild("numApogee").equalTo(user.getUserData_Session().get(SessionManager.KEY_NUM));
    CheckUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot)
        {
            String niveau_user=snapshot.child(user.getUserData_Session().get(SessionManager.KEY_NUM)).child("niveau").getValue(String.class);
            rootNode =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            reference = rootNode.getReference("etd");

            TextView text=findViewById(R.id.test);
            text.setText("niveau "+niveau_user);

            if(niveau_user.contains("Licence"))
            {
                list_hash.put(data_en_tete.get(0),maths_lc);
                list_hash.put(data_en_tete.get(1),info_lc);
            }
            else if(niveau_user.contains("Master"))
            {
                list_hash.put(data_en_tete.get(0),maths_ma);
                list_hash.put(data_en_tete.get(1),info_ma);
            }
            else
            {
                list_hash.put(data_en_tete.get(0),maths_doc);
                list_hash.put(data_en_tete.get(1),info_doc);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Userlistname.setonchlildclickListner after that
you can get text and any data on that position than you can startthatactivity

Here is Some Code about how to onclicklistnercalls

```
allitems.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
```

//Here is Example how to get any thing from position of a
child if you are using customelist r any

```
      Category_getter_setter 
      category_getter_setter=(Category_getter_setter) 

     ADD_CHILDS_extendable.get(items_extendable.get
         (groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
          //  
            return true;
        }
    });
```